# How to integrate eclipse (PyDev) with Python Add-In development (ArcGIS 10.1)?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-addin, eclipse

In ArcGIS 10.1, Python Add-Ins make various buttons, toolbars, extensions, etc, available to those already familiar with Python and OO in general. I am in the process of developing a Python Add-In and normally I would use eclipse with PyDev to develop scripts or small python applications. However, with the prescribed/predefined Python Add-In workflow (Python Add-In Wizard), I am finding it difficult integrating my eclipse workflow.

The Python Add-In relies on a script that packages the add-in according to a predefined config.xml and folder/file structure, seen below:

```
Python Add-In\
    Images\
        yourimages.png
    Install\
        PythonAddIn_addin.py
    config.xml
    makeaddin.py
```

How would you integrate eclipse PyDev without interfering with the python add-in wizard and prescribed development folder structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also use Eclipse with PyDev as my main Python editor for arcpy and non-arcpy scripts. If I decide to develop Python Add-ins in 10.1, I will probably just use NTFS [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) so that the file in the .py file in the Add-in folder is just a symbolic link to the actual .py file in my Eclipse folder. This is like a shortcut, but is seamless because it's created at the filesystem level. Programs (e.g. ArcMap) usually can't tell the difference between the actual file and a symbolic link to the actual file.

[This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) walks through the creation and use of symbolic links.

Comment: Aside from having my data stored on a mapped network drive, this worked. To overcome this, using a DVCS (I like tortoise HG) work on a local copy that I clone from the network and commit changes too throughout the day. Pull request to the network repository when ready.

Comment: I'd also add in for anyone else the possibility of a filesystem junction on windows if you need to symlink a whole folder. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx